# django dynamic number of named groups in url

Tags: regex, django, url-pattern

I would like to develop a web service with dynamic urls.

A common url pattern with named groups would be something like this:

```
(r'^articles/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive')
```

For my purpose I need a little more dynamic, because I don't know the number of groups from the beginning.

E.g. possible urls could be:

- articles/post/comments
- articles/post/author
- article/post/
  ...

I could use something like this:

```
(r'^(?P<cat1>)/(?P<cat2>)/$', 'module.views.function')
(r'^(?P<cat1>)/(?P<cat2>)/(?P<cat3>)/$', 'module.views.function')
(r'^(?P<cat1>)/(?P<cat2>)/(?P<cat3>)/(?P<cat4>)/$', 'module.views.function')
```

..
and so on. Is there a smarter way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this interests me, I've wanted it before but never came up with a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Wait if you only have 1 article then you want it to be `article/post/`, otherwise you want it to be `articles/post/`?

Since URLs are just regular expressions you could do something like

```
(r'^articles?/post/$', 'some_view')
```

the `?` tests either 0 or 1 of `s`.

But fundamentally your URLs don't seem to make sense, when you write `articles/post/comments`, it sounds like you want to post comments on **all** articles? Same with `article/post/`, what does that mean? Which article are you trying to post (you only have one and at most one)?

Typically URLs look like `articles/5/post/comments`, which would mean "I want to post comments on article with a pk of 5".

Sorry if my answer didn't help. I guess I didn't really understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, my example urls are misleading. The problem is more generic, its not about articles or posts, its about how to extract the info between the slashes if the number of slashes (named groups) is not known apriori.

Comment: Have you tried `(r'(?P<match>\w+)'` (note the missing `^` and `$`)? But I'm not sure if views can take a list for a matched named regex group. If that doesn't work then try `(r'^(?<match>.+)$'` (matches the entire URL) and split `match` for `/`.